# Adding Custom components with a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've been learning React and practicing with some basic stuff, and this is probably a very simple problem with an even simpler solution, but for the life of me I can't find what i need on google.

Basically i have this piece of code:

```
export default function BigContainer({ rain, icon, temperature, date }) {
  return (
    <div className='bigContainer'>
      <Container rain={rain[0]} icon={icon[0]} temperature={temperature[0]} date={date[0]} />
      <Container rain={rain[1]} icon={icon[1]} temperature={temperature[1]} date={date[1]} />
      <Container rain={rain[2]} icon={icon[2]} temperature={temperature[2]} date={date[2]} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The variables in question are simple arrays with either numbers or strings in them, nothing really important.

And I've been looking around for a way to not have to hardcode in the indexation of each property, since hardcoding this stuff isnt ideal.

I've tried mapping one of the arrays but i got kinda confused on how to implement the other properties with relation to the one array i was mapping, so I couldn't get that to work.

So yeah, if theres a way to do like

```
    Loop the stuff here{
      <Container rain={rain[i]} icon={icon[i]} temperature={temperature[i]} date={date[i]} />
    }
```

Or something similar, its basically what im looking for. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If each related variable is at same index, you can map using `Array.prototype.map()`. It's callback function gives you `index` as a second parameter. You can replace hardcoded index with the `index` of `.map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Array object like this;

```
const rain=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const icon=['icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3', 'icon4', 'icon5']
const temperature = [13, 15, 17, 14, 12]
```

You can use Array.map function like this;

```
[...Array(5)].map((item, idx)=>
    <Container
     rain={rain[idx]}
    icon={icon[idx]}
    temperature={temperature[idx]}
    key={idx}
    />
    )
```

Or when your data object array is ready, you can use Array.map like this.

```
const weathers=[
{rain:'rainy', temperature:11, date:'2020-04-01'},
{rain:'no rain', temperature:16, date:'2020-04-02'},
{rain:'drizzle', temperature:13, date:'2020-04-03'},
]

return (
    <>
         {
            weathers.map((value, idx) => (
                <table key={idx}>
                    <tr>
                     <th>rain</th>
                     <th>temperature</th>
                     <th>date</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>{value.rain}</td>
                     <td>{value.temperature}</td>
                     <td>{value.date}</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           ))}
    </>
    );
```

Comment: I have tried both solutions and for some reason the elements simply dont render on the page for some reason.
Edit: Turns out that after 10 minutes of checking it over, i was using a bracket over parentesis. Now it works fine. Thank you very much

Comment: I am happy to hear you've resolved the issue, hope you are doing well, could you please click upvote if you are fine?

Comment: Unfortunately i cant upvote yet since i dont have 15 reputation, whatever that means. Sorry, im pretty new here

Comment: No problem, I upvoted your question just now, hope you will get enough reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

try this you can replace [1,2] with your array you wish to map

```
[1,2].map((item,index)=>

  <Container rain={rain[index]}
             icon={icon[index]} 
             temperature={temperature[index]}
              date={date[index]} />
  )
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue with the rendering of the page trying this method. I've been trying to use one of the variables (rain, icon, etc) for the mapping function, but it doesn't work. You think it might have to do with the fact that these arrays start out empty and only fill up once i make an API call?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to render dynamic values in react. First you need to put the values in an object.

```
//For example put them in an array called weather and put the values 
  inside with key-value pairs. Then you can easily loop the values.



export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="bigContainer">
            {weather.map((value) => (
                <table>
                    <tr>
                     <th>rain</th>
                     <th>temperature</th>
                     <th>date</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>{value.rain}</td>
                     <td>{value.temperature}</td>
                     <td>{value.date}</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           ))}
       </div>
     );
    }
```

---

Comment: you can check the full solution here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-69oirw?file=/index.js:367-826

Answer (score 0):

you can also just pass an array of object instead of passing the array individually since they are related to each other

```html
 const weather = [
    {
      rain: 'rain1',
      icon: 'icon1',
      temperature: 'temp1',
      date: 'date1',
    },
    {
      rain: 'rain2',
      icon: 'icon2',
      temperature: 'temp2',
      date: 'date2',
    },
    {
      rain: 'rain3',
      icon: 'icon3',
      temperature: 'temp3',
      date: 'date3',
    },
  ]
```

```js
{weather.map((item, key) => (
    <div key={key} className='bigContainer'>
       <Container rain={item.rain} icon={item.icon} temperature={item.temperature} date={item.date} />
    
     </div>
))}
```

and map them like this